# wso2 api manager elk based analytics

Tags: wso2, elastic-stack

I'm trying to enable elk analytics for wso2 api manager 4.0.0 by following the official documentation but when i add the following configuration in deployment.toml `[apim.analytics] enable = true type="elk"` 
i got this error

> ERROR - gateway [SCR] Error while trying to bind reference Reference[name = api.manager.config.service, interface = org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIManagerConfigurationService, policy = dynamic, cardinality = 1..1, target = null, bind = setAPIManagerConfigurationService, unbind = unsetAPIManagerConfigurationService]
> Details:
> Problematic reference = Reference[name = api.manager.config.service, interface = org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIManagerConfigurationService, policy = dynamic, cardinality = 1..1, target = null, bind = setAPIManagerConfigurationService, unbind = unsetAPIManagerConfigurationService]
> of service component = org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.handlers
> component implementation class = org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.internal.APIHandlerServiceComponent
> located in bundle with symbolic name = org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway
> bundle location = reference:file:../plugins/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.0.174.jar
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ComponentReference.bind(ComponentReference.java:376) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.bindReference(ServiceComponentProp.java:430) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.bind(ServiceComponentProp.java:218) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:343) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:544) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.sequences.internal.SequenceEditorServiceComponent.activate(SequenceEditorServiceComponent.java:80) [org.wso2.carbon.sequences_4.7.99.jar:?]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:544) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer.activate(ServiceBusInitializer.java:213) [org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer_4.7.99.jar:?]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:544) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.persistence.service.InboundEndpointPersistenceServiceDSComponent.activate(InboundEndpointPersistenceServiceDSComponent.java:50) [org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.persistence_4.7.99.jar:?]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:544) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:529) [org.wso2.carbon.core_4.6.2.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.removePendingItem(CarbonServerManager.java:305) [org.wso2.carbon.core_4.6.2.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.bundleChanged(PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.java:118) [org.wso2.carbon.core_4.6.2.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:973) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: name
> at feign.Util.checkNotNull(Util.java:116) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
> at feign.Target$HardCodedTarget.(Target.java:78) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
> at feign.Target$HardCodedTarget.(Target.java:73) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
> at feign.Feign$Builder.target(Feign.java:265) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.am.analytics.publisher.auth.AuthClient.getSASToken(AuthClient.java:44) ~[org.wso2.am.analytics.publisher.client_1.0.1.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.am.analytics.publisher.client.EventHubProducerClientFactory.getSASToken(EventHubProducerClientFactory.java:59) ~[org.wso2.am.analytics.publisher.client_1.0.1.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.am.analytics.publisher.client.EventHubProducerClientFactory.create(EventHubProducerClientFactory.java:46) ~[org.wso2.am.analytics.publisher.client_1.0.1.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.am.analytics.publisher.client.EventHubClient.createProducerWithRetry(EventHubClient.java:94) ~[org.wso2.am.analytics.publisher.client_1.0.1.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.am.analytics.publisher.client.EventHubClient.(EventHubClient.java:72) ~[org.wso2.am.analytics.publisher.client_1.0.1.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.am.analytics.publisher.reporter.cloud.DefaultAnalyticsMetricReporter.(DefaultAnalyticsMetricReporter.java:63) ~[org.wso2.am.analytics.publisher.client_1.0.1.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.am.analytics.publisher.reporter.MetricReporterFactory.createMetricReporter(MetricReporterFactory.java:51) ~[org.wso2.am.analytics.publisher.client_1.0.1.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.common.analytics.publishers.impl.AnalyticsDataPublisher.initialize(AnalyticsDataPublisher.java:60) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.common.analytics_9.0.174.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.common.analytics.AnalyticsServiceReferenceHolder.setConfigurations(AnalyticsServiceReferenceHolder.java:46) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.common.analytics_9.0.174.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.internal.APIHandlerServiceComponent.setAPIManagerConfigurationService_aroundBody12(APIHandlerServiceComponent.java:227) ~[?:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.internal.APIHandlerServiceComponent.setAPIManagerConfigurationService(APIHandlerServiceComponent.java:214) ~[?:?]
> ... 94 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed the issue by getting the latest version 4.1.0

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.0.0/api-analytics/on-prem/elk-installation-guide/) the ELK Analytics feature is available as an update. You need to update WSO2 API Manager 4.0.0 to at least update level 90 to use this. You may refer [Updating WSO2 API Manager](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.0.0/administer/updating-wso2-api-manager/) to update the API Manager.

Comment: i tried to update to level 90 , but i got this error when updating : Checking for updates
wso2update: Error while getting update information: Unable to check for updates from server. Request to https://gateway.api.cloud.wso2.com/t/updateslive/updates/1.0.0/check-updates met with response code 500

Comment: i fixed the update issue and i got this message now: Checking for latest update tool version
A new update is available
Attempting to download and update the WSO2 Update Tool
Update tool client has been updated. Please re-run the tool with necessary parameters

Comment: Does this mean it got updated ? how can i check the new level ?

Comment: You need to re-run the tool. As joy mentioned you can use the current-state command to check the update level

Comment: this is what i got after running current-state "WSO2 product: wso2am-4.0.0.0
There are no hotfixes applied on this pack." i think the update didn't work , what does it mean by re-run the tool ??

Comment: Yeah, the updates haven't been installed. You need to run the update tool again. For example, if you are on Linux you can run it as `./wso2update_linux`. This will update the product to the latest version.

Comment: run the wso2update_windows.exe again to update to the latest product pack. also, I believe you have a trial or a valid subscription? you will be prompted to login using your credentials to the update server when you run the wso2update_windows.exe command.

Comment: At first you may need to run the relevant update command twice. First time you execute ./wso2update_<os> updates the Update Client Tool. The subsequent ./wso2update_<os> updates the product pack. You can check more details from https://updates.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/updates/update-tool/

Comment: i got this error when i re-run it : Checking for updates
wso2update: Error while getting update information: Unable to check for updates from server. Request to https://gateway.api.cloud.wso2.com/t/updateslive/updates/1.0.0/check-updates met with response code 500

Comment: @JoyRathnayake yes i entered my credentials but i always got the same error after running the update command for second time "Checking for updates
wso2update: Error while getting update information: Unable to check for updates from server. Request to https://gateway.api.cloud.wso2.com/t/updateslive/updates/1.0.0/check-updates met with response code 500"

Comment: @firas Are you behind a proxy server? If so could you please check this troubleshooting guide https://updates.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/updates/faq/#should-i-change-configurations-when-a-proxy-serverfirewall-is-running

Comment: @sanoJ , i just checked , i'm not using any proxy server

Answer (score 2):

No, it means it has updated the Update too to the latest version. You need to re-run the Update tool to update the product pack.

You can use **current-state** switch to check the current product pack version to see whether you are in the correct update level.

Comment: this is what got when i re-run wso2update_windows.exe "Checking for latest update tool version
-------------- Welcome to WSO2 Updates --------------

Checking for updates
wso2update: Error while getting update information: Unable to check for updates from server. Request to https://gateway.api.cloud.wso2.com/t/updateslive/updates/1.0.0/check-updates met with response code 500"